# next-i18next при вызове serverSideTranslations и смене url происходит переотрисовка файла _app.js

Tags: nextjs, i18n, next.js

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ locale }) {
    const data = await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['apple', 'home']);
    return {
        props: data,
    };
}

export default function IndexPage() {
  return <h1>Hi!</h1>
}
```

Я заметила, что если передать `data` в `props`, то при смене маршрутов в NextJS файл _app.js перерисовывает всё приложение вызывая мерцание, но если не передавать `data` в `props`, то все работает нормально. Как это можно исправить?

next-i18next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: 'fr',
        locales: ['fr', 'en'],
    },
    reloadOnPrerender: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
};
```

next.config.js

```
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    i18n,
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    poweredByHeader: false,
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/api/:path*',
                destination: 'http://localhost:8080/:path*',
            },
        ];
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, при переходе на страницу, где отсутствует подгрузка слов через serverSideTranslations это приводит к сбросу состояний _app.js и происходит ререндер. Для решения это проблемы необходимо для каждой странице указать вызов функций `serverSideTranslations`